# how copy teradata table to Azure sql with Azure function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database, teradata

I'm trying to copy data from one teradata table to a table in azure SQL using azure function, is this possible? can you give me a little example?

I can read the data with the teradata.client.provider, but I can't insert the data in the destination table in azure sql.

thanks u

Comment: You need to store the teradata table data into an entity and then insert it to Azure SQL.

Comment: Hi @Ergoliat, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't help you build the code but we can give some suggestions and ideas.

If you want copy data from one teradata table to a table in azure SQL using azure function, the workaround should like this:

1. Add bindings to Teradata table to get the data.
2. Using entity to store the Teradata data.
3. Then insert the entity to Azure SQL.

HTH.